# Generic class - operator issue

Tags: java, operator-keyword, generics

I'm trying to do a generic class in Java.
Reading some guides, I found how to declare it and also how to call its function as well.

My class is a point and without methods it would be in this way:

```
class Pnt<type>{
  protected type x, y;
  protected int col;
}
```

Now, I'm trying to make an `add` method, but I am not able to do it.

What I tried is:

```
  void add(type x_, type y_){
    x += x_;
    y += y_;
  }
```

The IDE is yelling at me that `+=` is undefined for `type` variables...

I know that in Java isn't possible to define a new operator like in C++, so I'm asking for an alternative way to add two `type` variables!

P.S. All the type that I will use would be `double`s, `float`s and `int`egers, that's why I'm trying to make a simple addiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems: First, if it should be fast, you have to use primitives directly, and these are not supported as a parameter in generics. This effectively means you have to maintain three versions for `Point` separately.

If you want to use generics, you can use the corresponding class (like `Integer`), but there is still one problem: Their super type `Number` does not have an `add` method (let alone a `+` operator or `+=`).

So the only way I know is to implement your own numeric class hierarchy which supports an `add` method:

```
abstract class Numeric<T extends Number> {
    public abstract T getValue();

    public abstract Numeric<T> add(Numeric<T> other);

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getValue().toString();
    }
}

class MyInt extends Numeric<Integer> {
    public final Integer value;

    public MyInt(Integer _value) {
        super();
        this.value = _value;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public Numeric<Integer> add(Numeric<Integer> other) {
        return new MyInt(this.value + other.getValue());
    }
}

class MyDouble extends Numeric<Double> {
    public final double value;

    public MyDouble(Double _value) {
        super();
        this.value = _value;
    }

    @Override
    public Double getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public Numeric<Double> add(Numeric<Double> other) {
        return new MyDouble(this.value + other.getValue());
    }
}
```

Based on this you can implement at least a generic point:

```
class NumericPoint<T extends Number> {
    public final Numeric<T> x;
    public final Numeric<T> y;

    public NumericPoint(Numeric<T> _x, Numeric<T> _y) {
        super();
        this.x = _x;
        this.y = _y;
    }

    public NumericPoint<T> add(NumericPoint<T> other) {
        return new NumericPoint<T>(this.x.add(other.x), this.y.add(other.y));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.x + "/" + this.y + ")";
    }
}
```

to be used with

```
NumericPoint<Integer> ip1 =
    new NumericPoint<Integer>(new MyInt(1), new MyInt(2));
NumericPoint<Integer> ip2 =
    new NumericPoint<Integer>(new MyInt(3), new MyInt(4));
NumericPoint<Integer> ip = ip1.add(ip2);
System.out.println(ip);

NumericPoint<Double> dp1 = 
  new NumericPoint<Double>(new MyDouble(1.1), new MyDouble(2.1));
NumericPoint<Double> dp2 = 
  new NumericPoint<Double>(new MyDouble(3.1), new MyDouble(4.1));
NumericPoint<Double> dp = dp1.add(dp2);
System.out.println(dp);
```

I have modified your example: The numerics and the points are *immutable*. It's implemented like `BigDecimal` for example. So the `add` method belongs to the generic class, and it returns a new instance.

Comment: Heavy, very heavy, I think I will have three different classes instead...
Unfortunately it doesn't fit my needs, but hey!
You made it possible! =D

Comment: I agree, it's heavy. It's `C++ templates` which solve this problem (C++ templates allow `int` as template parameter).

Comment: Yup, but Processing doesn't support C++!

Answer (score 3):

When you say `class Pnt<type>`, ti means that `type` is an object and not a primitive data type like `int` or `double`. You can perform `+=` operation on numeric primitive data types like `int`, `float`, etc and not on an object. In fact you can't perform the `+=` operation with any generic object.

The objects of `Integer`, `Float`, etc. support the `+=` operator, because they are wrapper classes and get unboxed to primitive types and autoboxed later. But the compiler has no way to confirm that the `type` will be an `Integer` or `Float`. Therefore, it generates a compile time error.

Comment: it's not working with object types either. In fact the statement fails at x+=x_; which is strange. I guess it has nothing to do with primitives.

Comment: That's explains why I have to use `Double` instead of `double` etc...
But the objects `Double`, `Float` and `Integer` support `+=` either!

Comment: Yes, `Integer` supports `+=` operator, but the compiler has no way of confirming whether the `type` will be an `Integer`. It could be a `File` or any other class.

Comment: You might try something like `class Pnt<type extends Number>`. Haven't tested this myself but it would indicate that the only legal classes are Numbers, which might be enough to make it compile.

Comment: @chessbot use ` symbol to wrap code in your comments. And no, it won't work using `type extends Number`. Note that `BigInteger` (among other classes) also extends from `Number` and do not support operations like `+=`. The fact that `Integer`, `Long` and other wrapper classes support this is because they are autoboxed to the primitive types and then the operation is performed on these primitives, then after the operation is done, the value is autoboxed one more time to `Integer` (or the wrapper class you were using).

Comment: @RahulBobhate `Integer` class alone doesn't support the `+=` operator. Refer to my comment to understand why *magically* works.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: +1 to your comment

Comment: So I have to re-write the same class for each type of number var that I need?